# What is the order of execution of the endpoint behaviors in WCF?

Tags: wcf, enterprise-library, endpointbehavior

What is the order of execution of the  endpoint behaviors in WCF ?
I want the logging to happen only if the request passes the validation block.
But in my case, even though the validation fails, the requests are logged by the auditing interceptor.

I have two behavior extensions:

```
<behaviorExtensions>
<add name="validation"/>
<add name="Auditing"/>
</behaviorExtensions>
```

and then in my behaviors:

```
<behaviors>
<endpointBehaviors>
<validation ruleset"AuthenticationRuleSet"/>
<Auditing />
</endpointBehaviors>
</behaviors>
```

Comment: Do you know how the validation and auditing behaviors are implemented? What WCF extension points are they using? In other words are they ParameterInspector, OperationInvoker, or something else?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From MSDN

> Evaluation Order
>
> The System.ServiceModel.ChannelFactory and the
>   System.ServiceModel.ServiceHost are responsible for building the
>   runtime from the programming model and description. Behaviors, as
>   previously described, contribute to that build process at the service,
>   endpoint, contract, and operation.
>
> The ServiceHost applies behaviors in the following order:
>
> Service
>
> Contract
>
> Endpoint
>
> Operation
>
> Within any collection of behaviors, **no order is guaranteed**.
>
> The ChannelFactory applies behaviors in the following order:
>
> Contract
>
> Endpoint
>
> Operation
>
> Within any collection of behaviors, again, **no order is guaranteed**.

For validation purposes, maybe you should take a look at Message Inspectors